# Overwrite fgdb table with R script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, modelbuilder

I am trying to overwrite an existing fgdb table with a R-script and the *arcgisbinding* package. I want to then place this script in Model Builder and use the resulting table in the rest of the model.

[image]

[image]

Here is a simplified version of the R-Script.

```
tool_exec <- function(in_params, out_params) {
  inTable <- in_params[[1]]
  dfOpen <- arc.open(inTable)
  df <- arc.select(dfOpen)
  df$A <- 0
  df$B <- "xxx"
  # Create the output table
  arc.write(inTable, df)
```

}

It gives the error:

> Error in .call_proxy : The table already exists.

I have tried giving the output table a different name, but then if I run the script again I end up with the same problem. 
If I change the Type of the OutputTable parameter from *Derived* to *Required* then I can specify a new table name each time (which I dont want to do) but then once I run the tool once, I have to specify the OutputTable location again manually.

Is there a way around this error?

**Notes** The box is ticked for the *Geoprocessing Options - Overwrite the outputs of geoprocessing operations*. I have very limited Python knowledge so that is why I am trying to do it in R & Model Builder.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

try adding these lines:

```
tool_exec <- function(in_params, out_params) {


inTable <- in_params[[1]]
**Output <- out_params[[1]]**
dfOpen <- arc.open(inTable)
df <- arc.select(dfOpen)
df$A <- 0
df$B <- "xxx"
# Create the output table
arc.write(inTable, df)
**return(out_params)**
```

It worked for me.